# Is working as content moderator halal

Tags: halal-haram, hadith

I recieved a job in a company as a content moderator for advertisements. The duty of my job is to review and remove the content online which might be suspicious or cause an unhealthy internet experience
The kinds of stuffs that are to be removed are "hate speech, any terror related ads, verbal abuse, child abuse even some adult content which includes pornographic images and nudity  "
My question is "Is it halal for me to do this job of removing this type of content?"

Comment: I've heard a lot about content moderation at Facebook with poor working conditions and a gag order - which to my mind is haram...

Answer (score 1):

salaam,
Yes, in my opinion, this is a perfectly fine job. In fact, it looks like you will be benefitting so many people by blocking this content. Even though there may be explicit content, your intention is pure and that is what is important. Please check out my profile for more information on my content.
Best,
Michelle

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaikum

Just basing it on the fact that you have to look through the content of advertisements and remove the content which is haraam or evil (ie explicit content).

Although it would mean that you are seeing haraam images the fact that you are removing them and only keeping the halaal for advertising along with the correct intention of getting people to step away from indecency and to live a more decent life would make the job halaal. However if it was the other way around and you had to actually advertise the explicit content then the job would be haraam because you would then be encouraging haraam but because with this job you are removing the explicit content and advertising the halaal content it's totally permissible just based on what you have mentioned the job entails. However if the job entails anything else too other than what you have already mentioned you might want to add it to here as that may change the outcome

Allah has restricted what is prohibited to the narrowest degree possible to all people but especially to Muslims and has made what is permitted wide.

Allah says (interpretation of meaning):
"Allâh wishes to make clear (what is lawful and what is unlawful) to you, and to show you the ways of those before you, and accept your repentance, and Allâh is All-Knower, All-Wise. Allâh wishes to accept your repentance, but those who follow their lusts, wish that you (believers) should deviate tremendously away (from the Right Path). Allâh wishes to lighten (the burden) for you; and man was created weak” [an-Nisa’ 4:25-27]

“Allâh intends for you ease, and He does not want to make things difficult for you”
[al-Baqarah 2:185]

“Allâh does not want to place you in difficulty, but He wants to purify you, and to complete His Favour to you that you may be thankful”
[al-Maa’idah 5:6].

Imam ash-Shaatibi (may Allah have mercy on him) said:
The basic principle with regard to interactions, transactions and customs is that they are permitted, unless there is evidence to the contrary.
al-Mawaafaqaat

And Allah knows best